# Is https://bintray.com a paid solution?

Tags: android, maven, aar, bintray, jcenter

I decided to upload my Android *aar library to Maven Central, I came to know that Android Studio uses JCenter by default and it is better than Maven Central. I tried to create an account on [bintray](https://bintray.com), but I've created a Trial Account.

1. How can I create a Open Source Account ?
2. Is JCenter a paid solution?
3. Is there any other alternatives for free
   maven?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about programming

Answer (score 6, accepted):

JCenter is free.
You can [signup](https://bintray.com/signup/oss) as Open Source Distribution.

[image]

<sup>I am with [JFrog](http://jfrog.com), the company behind [[image]bintray](/questions/tagged/bintray) and [[image]artifactory](/questions/tagged/artifactory).</sup>

Comment: This is what I'm looking for days. Thank you brother.